# Increment query takes long time to execute in MariaDB

Tags: database, mariadb, mariadb-10.2

The query below takes 0.005secs to 7secs to execute on the production server database but max 0.010 secs on the local database. Don't know what's wrong with the query.

Query:

```
UPDATE tbl_entrance_exam_report_info SET 
total_marks_obtained=total_marks_obtained+0.0, 
marks_obtained_from_overall_subjects=marks_obtained_from_overall_subjects+0.0, 
end_time=NOW(), 
total_solved=total_solved+1, 
overall_skipped_question_ids='', 
skipped_question_ids='', 
total_incorrect_answers=total_incorrect_answers+1 
WHERE id=4737
```

**Note:** Columns with +x increment are either int or float. Also, the production server database has been dumped and imported on the localhost and has 4k data.

`SHOW CREATE TABLE tbl_entrance_exam_report_info`:

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_entrance_exam_report_info` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `created_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `end_time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `start_time` datetime NOT NULL,
  `total_correct_answers` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `total_incorrect_answers` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `total_marks_obtained` float NOT NULL,
  `total_skipped` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `total_solved` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `admission_student_information_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `online_exam_set_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `team_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `exited` tinyint(1) DEFAULT 0,
  `overall_skipped_question_ids` longtext DEFAULT NULL,
  `skipped_question_ids` longtext DEFAULT NULL,
  `student_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `marks_obtained_from_overall_subjects` float NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `admission_application_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `college_admission_application_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `public_student_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `FK1B3AE9E19768BB6B` (`online_exam_set_id`),
  KEY `FK1B3AE9E1F94118FD` (`admission_student_information_id`),
  KEY `FK1B3AE9E17E2DE65F` (`team_id`),
  KEY `FK1B3AE9E18CFA03F5` (`student_id`),
  KEY `FKoq6i5nhgrsdcin3vxrwl6qout` (`admission_application_id`),
  KEY `FKfskks7r4xmjma8eckjdfmg9st` (`college_admission_application_id`),
  KEY `FKsmin66q8dcsuvm7rexdujrolm` (`public_student_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK1B3AE9E17E2DE65F` FOREIGN KEY (`team_id`) REFERENCES `tbl_team` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK1B3AE9E18CFA03F5` FOREIGN KEY (`student_id`) REFERENCES `tbl_student` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK1B3AE9E19768BB6B` FOREIGN KEY (`online_exam_set_id`) REFERENCES `tbl_online_exam_set_school` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK1B3AE9E1F94118FD` FOREIGN KEY (`admission_student_information_id`) REFERENCES `tbl_admission_student_application` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FKfskks7r4xmjma8eckjdfmg9st` FOREIGN KEY (`college_admission_application_id`) REFERENCES `tbl_college_admission_application` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FKoq6i5nhgrsdcin3vxrwl6qout` FOREIGN KEY (`admission_application_id`) REFERENCES `tbl_admission_application` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FKsmin66q8dcsuvm7rexdujrolm` FOREIGN KEY (`public_student_id`) REFERENCES `tbl_public_student` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4744 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

[SHOW GLOBAL STATUS](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1fl6IrAqdCqSN9D9-4oKRM2QfFugdi5jcYjLRn9OgDDk/edit?usp=sharing)

**Production server MariaDB details (slower one)**:

[image: Production server MariaDB details]

**Local server MariaDB details**:

[image: Local server MariaDB details]

Update:
***my.cnf with tuning changes:***

```
[mysqld]
max_allowed_packet = 1000M
max_connections = 9999
innodb_buffer_pool_instances    = 6     # Use 1 instance per 1GB of InnoDB pool size
innodb_buffer_pool_size         = 6G    # Use up to 70-80% of RAM
innodb_log_file_size = 256M

#cache
query_cache_type = 1
query_cache_limit = 256k
query_cache_min_res_unit = 2k
query_cache_size = 80M
```

***Server Info:***

```
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                20
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-19
Thread(s) per core:    1
Core(s) per socket:    1
Socket(s):             20
NUMA node(s):          1
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            6
Model:                 79
Model name:            Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2620 v4 @ 2.10GHz
Stepping:              1
CPU MHz:               2097.063
BogoMIPS:              4195.17
Hypervisor vendor:     Xen
Virtualization type:   full
L1d cache:             32K
L1i cache:             32K
L2 cache:              256K
L3 cache:              20480K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0-19
RAM:                   40GB
```

Comment: On server version is 10.2.31 and the other is 10.4.13? Which is the slower production server? Are you testing them with the same size dataset? Are you running out of memory on your production server? What else is happening on the production server? Is `id` the primary key of `tbl_entrance_exam_report_info`?

Comment: btw, the query is fine. There's something else in the environment going. Your production server mysql configuration, RAM, `show global status` and `show create table tbl_entrance_exam_report_info` information would be useful. Edit the question to include this.

Comment: Hi @danblack, thanks for your response. I have updated the question as per your last comments. Please have a look.

Comment: Disable your query cache for a start this could be the cause (its rarely useful). Include the my.cnf files you have on the server that contain tuning changes. How much RAM on the production server? You are creating a temporary table on disk every 2 seconds. Is your IO overloaded. You have problems with your `select` statements too to generate this many tmp tables on disk.

Comment: Thanks again. I have updated the question as per your last comment.

Comment: About how long were those two `longtext` columns before you cleared them?  `STATUS` is not very useful without `SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES`.  Please provide `SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'tbl_entrance_exam_report_info';`

Comment: It was empty from the beginning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disable query cache;

```
query_cache_type=0
query_cache_size=0
```

in configuration file for test run with `set global query_cache_type=0,query_cache_size=0`.

To see if this is still happening enable your query log:

```
slow_query_log=1
slow_query_log_file=/var/log/mysql/mariadb-slow.log
log_slow_verbosity=explain
long_query_time=1
```

(these also can be set at runtime).

Try to solve your slow queries on [dba stack exchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/).

Look up mechanisms for monitoring the io capacity and latency of your storage.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's faster than the previous one but still takes up to 2 seconds. I have applied all changes mentioned above. I will monitor it more and provide you the update.

Comment: Everything is fine till date. Thanks :)